# Entry Count plugin

Tags: plugin-development, entries, plugins, count

I'm trying to get the most popular entries of my site in a certain time period, for example 24h, based on the amount of views (clicks) it gets. I'm using the entry count plugin to do the counting but I can't get it working like I want. It can get a most viewed of all time array, but I need a most viewed of the last 24h.
I've followed the course that the plugin is based on, but I only get errors when trying to customize it...
Can anyone help me out? Thanks!

Comment: Hi Jan, I am sure native Twig can help out here. Can you show the code you are working with?

Comment: Hi Nutmeg,
Using the entry count plugin I call the "counted' entries like so: 
`{% set countedEntries = craft.entryCount.entries %}`
and this is the first problem, I can't seem to get them ordered by any way possible except by count number (tried by title, dateCreated, dateUpdated, id). So that's the first hurdle I need to pass. Once that's done, I need to calculate the amount that an article has been viewed in the last 30h, and sort the articles by that amount, setting a limit of 10

Answer (score 2):

The [Entry Count plugin](https://github.com/putyourlightson/craft-entry-count) does not record the individual times at which each entry was counted, therefore there is no way to filter by a specific time period. For that you'll need to find another solution.

**UPDATE:**

As you've requested it in the comments, the only way to get this to work without the existing plugin would be to reset all entry counts once a day using a cron job. For sure not ideal but it would require a minimal amount of code refactoring.

To set this up you would need to add an anonymous controller method (that requires a key to be accessed) to reset all entry counts:

```
public function actionResetAll()
{
    // verify query parameter key
    if (craft()->request->getParam('key') != 'xyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyz') {
        die('Unauthorised key');
    }

    craft()->entryCount->resetAll();
}
```

As well as a service method to do the work:

```
public function resetAll()
{
    // delete all records from DB
    EntryCountRecord::model()->deleteAll();

    // log reset
    EntryCountPlugin::log('All entry counts reset.');
}
```

Comment: Considering it is the course example, Ben - would it be possible (for students) to add this feature or the EntryModel to the plugin?

Comment: Sure, although it would require quite a bit of code refactoring.

Comment: I'm working on this again, is there any other way to get this done? Of are you working on it already @BenCroker?

Comment: Have added an update to my answer along with some code samples. Beyond this you're going to essentially have to write some code :)